# Creating a slide toggle transition inside a Knockoutjs custom binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, transition

Trying to toggle templates appearing within *virtual elements* using a sliding transition. While the slide-down transition is working, I need assistance pls with slide-up. So basically, when the virtual element appears, the templates within it automatically slide-in and when the 
virtual element hides the child templates should slide up.

Guess the solution should really making the virtual element itself slide up/down and not the child templates.

http://jsfiddle.net/XPYnv/

```
<script type="text/html" id="tpl">
<div>Hello world!!</div>
</script>   
<a href="#" data-bind="click: toggle">Toggle</a>

<!-- More detail here to show more complexity of production version -->
<!-- ko if: toggleState -->
<div data-bind="slideInTemplate: { name: 'tpl'}"></div>

<!--edit added to show complexity of production version-->
<div data-bind="slideInTemplate: { name: 'tpl2'}"></div>
       <!-- ko if: someOtherToggleState -->
       <div data-bind="slideInTemplate: { name: 'tpl3'}"></div>
       <!-- /ko -->
<!--end edit-->

<!-- /ko -->
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    toggleState: ko.observable(false),
    toggle: function () {
        this.toggleState(!this.toggleState());
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.slideInTemplate = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['template']['init'](element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);  
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.unwrap(value));
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        $(element).hide();
        ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.unwrap(value) ? $(element).slideDown() : $(element).slideUp(); 
    } 
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: A check for `$(element).is(":visible")` might help you out

Comment: This is the closest solution to what I require: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kNtdu, just need to integrate an option for "ifNotFade"...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are going after? See this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/XPYnv/3/

```
var viewModel = {};

window.ko.renderTemplateHtml = function (templateId, data) {
    ///<summary>Returns html from a KO template</summary>
    var node = $("<div />")[0];
    window.ko.renderTemplate(templateId, data, {}, node);
    return $(node);
};

ko.bindingHandlers.slideInTemplate = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var local = window.ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var options = {};

        ko.utils.extend(options, ko.bindingHandlers.slideInTemplate.options);
        ko.utils.extend(options, local);
        var templateId = options.kotemplate;
        var templateHtml = ko.renderTemplateHtml(templateId, viewModel);

        $(element).after(templateHtml);
        templateHtml.hide();

        $(element).bind('click', function () {
            templateHtml.slideToggle();
        });
    }

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

and the HTML:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tpl">
    <div>Hello world !!</div>
</script> 

<a href="#" data-bind="slideInTemplate: { kotemplate: 'tpl'}">Toggle</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, the example I gave with the click toggle was to conveniently change the observable value between true and false. In the production version this value is determined by events other than a click event. It's preferable to have this transition working with virtual elements.

Comment: See my new comment under question :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple problems in your binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideInTemplate = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      return ko.bindingHandlers['template']['init'](element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
```

Nothing after this will be executed in your `init` function. Take the `return` off the previous statement.

```
    var value = valueAccessor();
```

Here `value` will be the object that you passed to the binding, e.g. `{name: tpl}`. You need to get the value of the appropriate member, i.e.

```
    var value = valueAccessor().name;
```

...

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
    $(element).hide();
    ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
    var value = valueAccessor();
```

Same thing here.

```
    ko.unwrap(value) ? $(element).slideDown() : $(element).slideUp(); 
}
```

};

Comment: No difference I'm afraid: http://jsfiddle.net/68jBR/. I think the problem is the parent virtual element turns off it's own visibility immediately thereby not giving the template enough time to display the slide-up effect.